# spawning random enemies with an array

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently making a game where I need random enemies from my array, to spawn in a random location on repeat. This code seems to work okay other than the fact that it can only rotate through each Enemy once. It comes up with an error saying "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent". Any help? Here is my current code:

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
       return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
   }
   
func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
       return random() * (max - min) + min
   }



func spawnEnemy() {
    
    let EnemyArray = [Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3, Enemy4, Enemy5, Enemy6]
    let randomElement = EnemyArray.randomElement()!
    self.addChild(randomElement)
    
    var moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(y: -800, duration: 4.0)
    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let EnemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
       randomElement.run(EnemySequence)

    }


 func runEnemy() {

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnEnemy), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)])))
    
}
```

Comment: You likely need to create a *new instance* of your enemy objects and not try to add the same ones over and over. Also, consider using the Swift standard practice of using lowercase letters to start variable names and reserve uppercase letters for types -- it'll make it easier for others (and eventually you) to read your code.

Comment: @jnpdx Hey thank you, do you mind showing me what something like that would look like? And I will definitely take your suggestion going forward!

Comment: I can't show you what it would look like, because I don't know what type `Enemy1` is, much less how to create another one -- none of that is represented in the code.

Answer (score 0):

as jnpdx suggested, you should spawn new instances of your Enemy class rather than starting with an array of them. you can introduce randomness inside the Enemy class -- for example a random start position or a random color. i would also put your movement and `removeFromParent` code inside the class as well. You didn't post your Enemy code, but it might look something like this

```
class Enemy:SKNode {
    var shape:SKShapeNode?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        //how ever you want to graphically represent your enemy... using a SKShapeNode for demo
        shape = SKShapeNode(ellipseOf: CGSize(width: 20, height: 40))
        shape?.fillColor = .blue
        addChild(shape ?? SKNode())
        
        //randomize starting x position
        position.x = CGFloat.random(in: -200...200)
        position.y = 200
        move()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //move and remove this node using SKAction
    func move() {
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -200, duration: 4.0)
        let delete = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, delete])
        self.run(sequence)
    }
}
```

then you would simply activate your spawn point from `didMove(to view: SKView)` like this

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {    
    runSpawnPoint()
}

func runSpawnPoint() {
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnEnemy), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)])))
}

func spawnEnemy() {
    let enemy = Enemy() //a brand new Enemy object each time
    addChild(enemy)
}
```

optional: save your spawned Enemy objects in an array if you want to access them later. alternately you can simply query `self.children` from your `SKScene` since they're all stored there as well. in which case you don't need an additional array for storage.

Comment: Yes! so this is essentially my code at the moment, I guess the problem is using multiple textures for the Enemy, so I can spawn different color enemies at random, instead of just spawning the same textured enemy. Is there any way to pick a random texture from an array and spawn the enemy with that texture? @Fault

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. So originally my problem was trying to spawn multiple, different-looking enemies, at random. I realized that I could solve the same issue by changing the texture of the Enemy, instead of creating many different Enemy Nodes. In order to spawn enemies at random with an array of textures, it would look something like this:

```
var enemy1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy1")
var enemy2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy2")
var enemy3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy3")
var enemy4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy4")
var enemy5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy5")
var enemy6 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Enemy6")


    let EnemyArray = [Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3, Enemy4, Enemy5, Enemy6]
    let randomElement = EnemyArray.randomElement()!
    
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "")
    enemy.name = "Enemy"
    enemy.texture = randomElement
    enemy.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    enemy.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(enemy)
    
    var moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(y: -800, duration: 4.0)
    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let EnemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
    enemy.run(EnemySequence)

    }


 func runEnemy() {

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnEnemy), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)])))
    
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help